# Comparing SHA-512 Salted Hashes, displays filename during execution

Tags: bash, sha512

Long story short during execution, i noticed that the `"*"` in the LIST somehow displays the name of the file i was executing. Is there anyway to let the code display `"*"` instead of displaying the filename ?

I am still a script newbie, could not think of any way. Please help ...

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST='W 2 v * %'
encr="Cd9AjUI4nGglIcP3MByrZUnu.hHBJc7.eR0o/v0A1gu0/6ztFfBxeJgKTzpgoCLptJS2NnliZLZjO40LUseED/"

salt="8899Uidd"
for i in $LIST
  do
   for j in $LIST
    do
    for k in $LIST
     do
      for l in $LIST
        do
        for a in $LIST
            do
            echo -n "$i$j$k$l$a "

   test=`mkpasswd -m SHA-512 $i$j$k$l$a -s $salt`
    if [ $test == $encr ] ; then
            echo " Password is: $i$j$k$l$a"
            exit
        fi
        done
       done
      done
    done
done

#error displaying *
```

[image: Executed filename displayed]

Answer (score 2):

The same as `echo *` expands the globulation `*` to the filenames in the current directory, the same way `a=*; for i in $a; do echo $i; done` will print paths in the current directory. You can read more about quotes and escaping at various places in the net.

You can use bash arrays to correctly quotes elements:

```
LIST=(W 2 v "*" %)
for i in "${LIST[@]}"; do
```

Notes:

- Don't use backticks `, they are discouraged. Use `$(..)` instead.
- Quote your variables expansions `[ "$test" = "$encr" ]` to protect from common bugs like this.
- The `==` is a bash extension, use `=` to be portable.
- The method for generating permutations of elements looks strange and is not scalable. Consider writing a function or using other method. Even (ab-)using bash extension [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) `echo {W,2,v,"*",%}{W,2,v,"*",%}{W,2,v,"*",%}{W,2,v,"*",%}{W,2,v,"*",%}` looks shorter.